# How to divide locale files in a modular express app with i18n-node?

Tags: node.js, express, localization, internationalization, i18n-node

I'm using i18n-node to translate a multilingual express web-app.
The i18n-node package allows you to specify a single folder for all of the locale json files which contain all the strings in the UI of the app.
Assuming the app is getting bigger & bigger, It would've been ideal to be able to divide the long monolithic language locale json which holds ALL of the app strings into separate files, each will reside in its custom module folder. Is there a way to specify multiple locale folders/files?
Cheers
Ajar

Comment: Same question here... have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose exists i18next package which supports namespaces.
But from my experience if you're looking for namespaces only - there are not so many profits in it. Because in the end of application bootstrapping all the namespaces will be loaded into memory.
The question is - do you want better editing feelings using namespaces?

Btw, i18next has many other benefits, if you need them.
For today my choice is old simple i18n.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I'll look into it and let you know.
Cheers :)